# A way to aggregate and group items for an activity feed using javascript

Tags: javascript, grouping, aggregate-functions, underscore.js, aggregation

I have a list of activity stream items where I want similar items to be grouped together.  For instance, instead of having 4 entries that say "Joe liked your happy post", "Sarah liked your happy post", "Bob liked your happy post", "Tom liked your happy post", there should be one that says "Joe, Sarah, and 2 others liked your happy post".  When items get aggregated, the aggregated post will use the most recent time stamp of its parts.

The activity stream is not endless and only contains items from the past week, so all items that match on the properties of noun(noun.activityType + noun.id), and verb should be grouped together.  Each activity item has an actor (who did it), target (who's feed is it posted to), verb (what did the actor do) and noun (what object was the verb acting on).

I've put this test dataset on jsfiddle for you guys to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/yu2P8/1/

```
{
        "pts": 0,
        "verb": "follow",
        "target": "mike",
        "actor": "test01",
        "title": "test01 has started following you",
        "published": "2012-06-04T22:34:01.914Z",
        "_id": "4fcd37d9c7f1f40100000d7d",
        "noun": {
            "id": "mike",
            "activityType": "profile",
            "title": null
        }
}
```

One strategy is to aggregate server side on creation of the activity item, but I wanted to explore doing this on the client side using libraries like underscore to see if it was doable.

Comment: Monkey Bonkey, how are you generating that JSON? From tables in your database?

Comment: 2 ways, one is from a database query and another is a batched stream from logs.

Comment: Can you share an example of DB Schema that would produce something like your output here? For example, is noun a table of its own? I have produced JSON outputs but never like this? I've never been able to find the answer on the Internet.

Comment: I'm using a document database (mongo) so it's schemaless.  Each object roughly follows the activity streams spec.

Comment: Mongo, I had a feeling you would respond this way. How would something like this be implemented with MySQL? I am curious.

Comment: I would just create an activities table with a column for all the activity stream properties such as noun, verb, target, etc..

Comment: That would never return the result as yours, where "noun" acts as if it is a different table with its own columns (id, activityType, title), please @MonkeyBonkey explain to me how MySQL can return it in that structure so that I can only JSON_ENCODE and print();

Comment: sorry, I don't use MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I worked this out using underscore group and map.  I first use the underscore group by using noun and verb as the key.  Then I use the underscore reduce function to combine the results into one entry.

```
var groupedResults = _.groupBy(data, function(val){
  return val.noun.id + val.noun.activityType + val.verb;
});

function reducer(activities, key) {
  var reduction = _.reduce(activities, function(a, b){
      if (a && a.actors && !_.include(a.actors, b.actor))
          a.actors.push(b.actor);
      else
          a.actors = [b.actor];
      a.published = a.published < b.published ? b.published : a.published;
      return a;

    }, activities[0]);

  reduction.pronoun = getActorsSummaryString(reduction);
  reduction.title = summarizeTitle(reduction);

  return reduction;
}

finalResults = sortByRecent(_.map(groupedResults, reducer));
```